# How to get the instance reference of the ViewModel, created by MEF container?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, prism, mef

A WPF Prism app's View gets its ViewModel instance with the help of MEF container:

```
    [Import]
    public MyModuleViewModel ViewModel
    {
        set { this.DataContext = value; }
    }
```

How could I get the reference of this VieModel's instance in the code-behind of the View?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var vm = DataContext as MyModuleViewModel;
```

?